# Dynamic field type?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have the following code:

```
queryProjects = queryProjects
    .Where(a => a.Field<int>("ProjectType") == projectType
        && a.Field<string>("Descr")
            .IndexOf(@str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
        || a.Field<string>("ProjectId")
            .IndexOf(@str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
        || a.Field<string>("LastChangedBy")
            .IndexOf(@str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
    );
```

How can I make the `a.Field< ??? >` the data type dynamic where the question marks are?

Comment: Have you tried using `a.Field<dynamic>`?  If so, what does it do?  If you get an error message, what is the error message?  Can you edit your question and add this info?

Answer (score 0):

On the type where your field property is, redefine it like so:

```
public T Field<T>(string key) 
{
  object field = null; // Get your field value here
  return (T)field; 
}
```